# Stop Execution if Vlan not found

Tags: ansible

I want to add a condition to stop execution of playbook if "vlan not found". I am attaching my playbook tasks below:

```
  - name: check vlan availability
    ios_command:
      commands:
        - show vlan id {{ vlan1 }}
    register: precheck

  - name: check voice_vlan availability
    ios_command:
      commands:
        - show vlan id {{ vlan2 }}
    register: precheck_voice_vlan

  - name: L2 Vlan1 Availability Check
    debug:
      msg: "Vlan not present in the switch"
    when: "'not found' in precheck"

  - name: L2 Vlan2 Availability Check
    debug:
      msg: "Vlan not present in the switch"
    when: "'not found' in precheck_voice_vlan"

===========here I want stop playbook execution if vlan not found========

  - name: get interface status from the device
    ios_command:
      commands:
        - show run int {{ interface }} | i trunk
    register: precheck_int
```

if Vlan not found in precheck I want to stop further execution .Please help me for this.

Comment: What have you tried? See the following modules: `assert`, `fail`, `meta`.

Comment: According the documentation you could [fail with a custom message](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/fail_module.html#ansible-builtin-fail-fail-with-custom-message), [asserts given expressions are true](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/assert_module.html#examples) or just [meta: end_play](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/meta_module.html#parameters).

Answer (score 0):

What about using `fail` [documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/fail_module.html)
It will go along with something like this

```
- name: Example using fail and when together
  fail:
    msg: The system may not be provisioned according to the CMDB status.
  when: cmdb_status != "to-be-staged"
```

Change the when with the VLAN condition